# Is it safe to run an electrical cable through an insulated exterior wall?

Tags: electrical, security

I have a Nest outdoor security camera that I want to place on the outside of my house and I would like to drill through the insulated wall and plug it into an outlet which is directly on the other side of that wall. Would it be safe to do this? Is it safe to run an electrical wire through a wall with insulation in it or is there a better way to do this? I don't want this to become a fire hazard if I go this route.

Comment: Just for clarification, the Ring is Low Voltage.

Comment: Is it a wall wart? One that plugs in and transforms the voltage to 12/24 volts? Going through a wall with a 120v cord would be an issue. But low voltage , not code , but probably not a fire issue either.

Comment: What voltage are we dealing with?  120V mains, or the low voltage output of a "wall wart"?  Will you be using approved wiring methods?

Comment: Its a USB cord that connects to a 120 adapter that plugs into a receptacle. This is the camera. https://store.google.com/product/nest_cam_outdoor_specs. If this is an issue, how would I run it through the wall? With conduit?

Comment: As stated earlier, this is Low Voltage, It's a USB cable (5v) straight through the wall.

Comment: It is safe.  You've probably seen outlets on the insides of exterior walls.   They have to run the wiring through the insulated wall to the outlets.

Comment: It's fine, go ahead. That's exactly how it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to imagine a problem. I did this for my sprinkler (low voltage) power supply. When I put 110 V wire through the wall, I usually use conduit, but I must have skipped the conduit once. The house has 5 exterior receptacles put in by a professional electrician, none with conduit (conduit is not generally required in TX)